# Enable 32 bit Applications azure paas cloud services

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, crystal-reports

When I export crystal report to PDF format I'm getting the following error. Please tell me a solution for this.
thank you.

[image]

Comment: You've missing log4net assembly/file reference. Check if the assembly is already referenced in web.config & loaded properly on the page.

Comment: i had this issue on my local machine.i enable the 32 bit application true on the default application pool.after that report work successfully.but when i publish the web on azure pass cloud server i'm getting this same error.unfortunately there were no default application pool on azure pass cloud server.how can i enable that 32 bit on server ? thanks # Tetsuya Yamamoto#